# When the number of matrices become infinity in a matrix inequality?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, infinite-matrices

I will first show my matrix inequality, and state my confusion after it. Suppose we have $n$ positive semi-definite matrices $M_i$ which further satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n{M_i}=I$. The dimension of $M_i$ is $d$, a finite number. Then I have the following matrix inequality
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
 M_1&  0&  0\\
 0&  ...&  0\\
 0&  0&  M_n\\
\end{matrix} \right) \succcurlyeq \left( \begin{array}{c}
 M_1\\
 ...\\
 M_n\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 M_1&  ...&  M_n\\
\end{matrix} \right) .$$
To see this, we only need to mind that
$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
 M_1\\
 ...\\
 M_n\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 M_1&  ...&  M_n\\
\end{matrix} \right) =\left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  0&  0\\
 0&  ...&  0\\
 0&  0&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 \sqrt{M_1}\\
 ...\\
 \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  ...&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  0&  0\\
 0&  ...&  0\\
 0&  0&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
\\
\preceq \left( \begin{matrix}
 M_1&  0&  0\\
 0&  ...&  0\\
 0&  0&  M_n\\
\end{matrix} \right) $$
where I have used the fact that
$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \sqrt{M_1}\\
 ...\\
 \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  ...&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 \sqrt{M_1}\\
 ...\\
 \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  ...&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \sqrt{M_1}\\
 ...\\
 \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  ...&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) $$
that is, $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \sqrt{M_1}\\
 ...\\
 \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{M_1}&  ...&  \sqrt{M_n}\\
\end{matrix} \right) $ is a projection. I wonder when $n$ tends to infinity, will the matrix inequality still exist?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is really how to interpret your inequality for $n = \infty$.  It should make sense as a statement about linear operators on an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space. Let Hilbert space $\mathcal H = \mathcal K \oplus \mathcal K \oplus \ldots$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of Hilbert space $\mathcal K$;
for each natural number $i$ let $M_i$ be a positive definite bounded linear operator on $\mathcal K$, with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i = I$.  The left side of your inequality is
the operator $L: \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$ defined by
$$L(x_1,x_2, \ldots) = (M_1 x_1, M_2 x_2, \ldots)$$ and the right side is $AB$ where
$B: \mathcal H \to \mathcal K$ is defined by
$$ B(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i x_i $$
and $A: \mathcal K \to \mathcal H$ is defined by
$$ A x = (M_1 x, M_2 x, \ldots)$$
and the inequality says $L - AB$ is positive definite.  That is, for every
$x = (x_1,x_2, \ldots) \in \mathcal H$,
$$ \langle x, (L - AB) x \rangle \ge 0$$
i.e.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle x_i, M_i x_i \rangle 
 \ge \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle M_i x_i, M_j x_j \rangle $$

[EDIT] The proof can be adapted from the matrix case.  Positive definite bounded linear operators have unique positive definite square roots, which I'll denote using $\sqrt{\ }$.  If
$C: \mathcal K \to \mathcal H$ and $D: \mathcal H \to \mathcal K$ are defined by  $$\eqalign{ C x &= (\sqrt{M_1} x, \sqrt{M_2} x, \ldots)\cr D(x_1, x_2, \ldots) &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sqrt{M_i} x_i \cr}$$
then $DC = I$ so $CD$ is a projection.  Note that $C^* = D$.  Then
$CD \preceq I$ so $$AB = \sqrt{L} C D \sqrt{L} \preceq \sqrt{L} \sqrt{L} = L$$

Comment: Oh, thanks. But since this time I cannot write $M_i$ as a block of a matrix, the proof of your last inequality cannot use my projection method?